# executing variable in system("") in C++

Tags: c++

I want to execute a variable inside `system("")`. For example like

```
system("iptables -i input -s VARIABLE -j drop")
```

VARIABLE here is an IP address but it'll change everytime.

how can i do that in C++ ? if it's not , then what's the solution ?

Comment: Didn't `system("iptables -i input -s $VARIABLE -j drop")` work? What's your operating system?

Comment: try  std::execl. usage example is : execl( "/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char*)0 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `std::string` for the command:

```
std::string cmd = "iptables -i input -s ";
std::string ipaddr = "192.168.11.22";
cmd += ipaddr;
cmd += "  -j drop";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Or a bit simpler using `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::string ipaddr = "192.168.11.22";
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "iptables -i input -s " << ipaddr << " -j drop";
system(oss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: I not sure if it is that much simpler - 6 of one and half a dozen of the other

Comment: thank you so much, it works... and i try this with the array string, and it works too. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string cmd = "iptables -i input -s ";
cmd += VARIABLE;
cmd += " -j drop";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Here the command is constructed to include the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You generate the string at runtime. For example:

```
std::string varip = somefunctiongivingastring();
std::string cmdstr= "iptables -i input -s " + varip + " -j drop";
```

Then you pass it to `system` by converting it to a raw `const char*` with

```
system (cmdstring.c_str());
```

You could do the same in C like

```
char cmdbuf[256];
char* varip = somfunctiongivingacstring();
snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "iptables -i input -s %s -j drop", varip);
```

However, beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection); imagine what could happen if `somefunctiongivingacstring()` would return the `"127.0.0.1; rm -rf $HOME; echo "`string

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the string at run-time using the following code (the ip address can be replaced with a string variable):

```
std::string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "iptables -i input -s " + ipAddress + " -j drop";
system(ss.str());
```

In order to compile this code correctly you need to include the following header file:

```
#include <sstream>
```